# 'The money Will transfer tomorrow' or 'the money will be transferred tomorrow'?

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is correct:
'The money will transfer tomorrow' or 'The money will be transferred tomorrow'?

Answer (score -1):

The money is an object, not a subject. Meaning it can't do something -for example, transferring- by itself. So "The money will transfer" is wrong because it means just that.

"The money **will be transferred** tomorrow" means that transferring process will be done to the money, by someone/something else, not the money itself. Which makes more sense.

Comment: "Money" *can* be a subject. Money solves a lot of problems.  On the other hand, money can't buy me love.  In fact, saying "money can't do something by itself" is a clear example of using "money" as a subject.

Comment: "Money solves a lot of problems" Yes it **does** haha :] I can confirm. I was referring to the money + the verb in question anyway. Thanks for the input.